# Python Socket Using Select To Check For Data

Tags: python, sockets, select

I found the following code on another post that works pretty good:

```
UDP_IP = ''
UDP_PORT = 5008
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', UDP_PORT))
while 1:
  socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]
  # Get the list sockets which are readable
  read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
  for sock in read_sockets:
   #incoming message from remote server
   if sock == s:
      data = sock.recv(4096)
      if not data :
        print '\nDisconnected from server'
        sys.exit()
      else :
         #print data
         sys.stdout.write(data)

   #user entered a message
   else :
     msg = sys.stdin.readline()
     s.send(msg)
```

The problem I've got is with the for loop since it only runs through it when there is data received.  I would really like it to use a while loop and have it occasionally check on if data has been received but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Replace the `sys.stdout.write(data)` with your checks.

Comment: I will always suggest an asynchronous programming framework in favor of low level socket programming.

Comment: I tried replacing sys.stdout.... but it didn't help.  It still only runs when I send data.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Huazuo for the post - I'm still trying to figure out how to get your suggestions working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the timeout parameter in the select statement. If no data is available (indicated by empty lists), you can do whatever other processing is needed in the body of the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried doing as you suggested but I can't get it to loop since it keeps waiting for data to be received. @sureshvv

Comment: On what line is it waiting? What is your timeout value? Are you checking the return value from select? Seems like you should debug your code.